# How to make statements using two collections in one future builder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in my Firestore DB, one is **Movies** and the other is **WatchLater**. What I'm trying to do is make if statement using both collections in one (**FutureBuilder**, **StreamBuilder**, etc..), for example:

```
if(Movies[index]['Movie_Name'] == WatchLater[index]['Movie_Name']){

// do something 

}
```

but it's not working because each collection has a different number of documents (indexes).
So is it possible to achieve what I want? and how? Thanks.

Comment: There's *a lot* of context missing here, which makes it hard to help. Can you make sure the code snippet, while minimal, is standalone so that we can all see everything needed. E.g. what is `i`, how are `Movied` and `WatchLater` initialized, where in your app is this code run, etc?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it's known that **i** means **index** in coding, I see that my question is clear, just how to compare between two documents from two different collections, no matter how. No need for complexity.

Comment: The question is unclear - why would you expect two distinct collections to have the same movie name at a specific index? Does your structure force a movie name to be *at* a specific index? In other words why would you expect Movies[4] to ever be the same movie as WatchLater[4]. And what if the WatchList is sorted by say, the year the movie came out? That would change all of the indexes.  @FrankvanPuffelen "i" is for index! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like that.

##### The simple exapmple:

```dart
// Collections.
List<String> movies = ['Superman', 'Batman', 'Spiderman'];
List<String> watchLater = ['Spiderman', 'Batman', 'Superman', 'Batman'];

// Find movie.
final movie = movies.firstWhere(
  (name) => name == 'Batman',
  orElse: () => 'Unknown',
);

/// Check if contains in the `watchLater` list
print(watchLater.contains(movie)); // output: true
```